# alternative to include a maven dependency

Tags: maven

I'm working with a simple project with android and I have to use an external library. In the documentation it only explains how to add this library using maven, since I'm having some issues using maven and android, I would like to know if there is a way of using this library not including maven in the project.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is a way of using this library not including maven in the project

Yes, you can download the library from the maven central website and then place it in the projects class-path. This way it will be treated just as an external library and your project will still remain free from being maven-ized.

Every jar that is in the maven central repository can be downloaded and imported as a external library in your project.

Comment: If you have the library with your-self, then (assuming you are using Eclipse), simply add it as an external library in your application and it will appear in your project's class-path

Comment: yes, I thought that, but this library is not in the maven central repo. I would have to put this inside the repositories tag: <url>https://github.com/mercadolibre/java-sdk-repo/raw/master/snapshots</url> but actually the problem is that I don't want to use maven for such a small project

Comment: I just checked the url that you gave and I can see the jar at [this location](https://github.com/mercadolibre/java-sdk-repo/blob/master/snapshots/com/mercadolibre/sdk/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/sdk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) .. Download it from here and then add it in the class-path

Comment: wow I saw a lot of jars there didn't know if one of those would be the correct, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Every maven dependency is eventually translated to a URL, which you can access with a simple `wget <url>` command.
I strongly suggest not breaking or overruling the maven dependency mechanism. Its there for a good reason and is loved by many... :-)
Maybe posting your maven issues will help getting some ideas for fixing them.

I hope this helps.

Comment: the thing is that I'm working with a very small project and I don't want to use maven only for one dependency. I would like to have a .jar to import or something but in the library documentation I only have the indications to include the dependency and repo in a maven project. not sure if I'm explaining myself